# Short circuit condition fail

Tags: c#

I've a bit problem with a short circuit condition, what I need to do is check if an array have almost 2 indexes or a string is equal to a certain value, to recreate the problem here, suppose this:

```
string[] favItem = new string[] { "hello", "world", "test", "foo" };
string temp = "hello";
var itemToRemove = temp.Split(',');

foreach(var fav in favItem)
{
   if(fav == "foo" || (itemToRemove.Length > 1 & fav == itemToRemove[0] || fav == itemToRemove[1]))
   {
     //do something
   }
}
```

so essentially I need to compare `fav` with a default value, if this fail, I need to check if the `itemToRemove` array have almost 2 indexes, if yes I need to compare the `fav` value in iteration, with the two indexes of `itemToRemove`.

Now suppose that in `itemToRemove` there is only one index, I'm not able to exit from this:

```
(itemToRemove.Length > 1 & fav == itemToRemove[0] || fav == itemToRemove[1])
```

in particular with `&` I'm trying to exit from the condition if the indexes aren't two.

In the debug mode I can see the `false` value with the breakpoint, but I don't understand why the code fall to:

> OutOfRangeException

with `itemToRemove[1]` when should be leave the condition.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: General rule of thumb is that you almost never want to use the non-short-circuiting operators `&` and `|` when dealing with `bool` logic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code has two problems.

First, the short-circuiting boolean "and" operator is `&&`. `&` is the bitwise and operator, and does not short circuit.

Secondly, `&&` has a higher precedence than `||`, so you need to group the second `||` together like this `(itemToRemove.Length > 1 && (fav == itemToRemove[0] || fav == itemToRemove[1]))`. The rule of thumb to remember precedence is that `and` is like multiplication `0 && 1 = 0`, while `or` is like addition `0 || 1 = 1`.

Answer (score 1):

[Short circuit is `&&` not `&`.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: I also tried with && but the exception is even trown